# Warnings and errors (CS0436, CS0234) when creating user controls composed of other user controls in the same project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a Windows Forms solution with many winform ui projects.
There is a class library project that contains some custom shared controls, named `MyControls`.

Now, when I create a control in `MyControls` 
that is composed of one or more controls in the same project, I run into problems.

I either get compilation warnings: warning CS0436: The type 'MyType' in 'path-to\MyType.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'MyType' in 'MyControls.dll'. Using the type defined in 'path-to\MyType.cs'. Or I get a bunch of different compilation errors, all pointing to "MyControls.dll" (error CS0234 - "are you missing an assembly reference?").

I get either the errors, or the warnings, never both.

How to solve this?

*Note*

I added [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010) because that's the version I experienced the problems with. No idea if this relates to other versions too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that Visual Studio adds a self-reference to `MyControls` when I drop a control from the `MyControls` project on another control in `MyControls`:

```
<Reference Include="MyControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

My current work-around is to manually delete this reference from the `MyControls.csproj` using a text editor.
When I've done this, everything works fine, until I drop another control that triggers a self reference.

Better solutions are appreciated!

Comment: this is **the** solution. I had the same error for a windows forms project. Never realized VS adds the assembly I'm building under references in the solution explorer. Removing it removes this warning and also gets rid of a weirder error that prevents you from debugging the exe if a previously built exe is in the bin.

Comment: I think, this is NOT a solution. I agree it solves the problem, however, you need to manually delete the reference after each control that is inserted to the form, which is ridiculous. I was also searching for some solution, but without success, so cannot help with it :(.

Comment: Ridiculous indeed, but I haven't found a better solution either.

Comment: This also fixed the problem for a MVC3 web site.  Not sure what caused the compiler warning to start occurring, no controls were dropped and the conflict referred to the MvcApplication class defined in Global.asax (ie a class in the same project)

Answer (score 1):

you can make a small and "legal" change in your solution and get the "legal" solution... lets say your project name is: "project01"
go to references folder in your project - one of your references called "project01" - just remove it...
the the warning is very fair! you design a form and in the other hand import your project as a reference!

Comment: Well, in my case the self reference to `project01` is not visible in Visual Studio. That's one of the annoying things. I'm using VS 2010. Are you saying you did the same, got the warning AND saw the self-reference in `project01`?

Comment: And note that I did not explicitly added the self-reference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I just went looking for a solution to this issue, and it seems that MS doesn't have anything other than what Marijn suggested earlier:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613502/automatically-add-self-reference

Hopefully it's fixed in VS 2012.